# webview content height

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am facing one problem.  What I am doing is:

I am loading 3 html pages inside webview in sequence in android and after loading each page want to get the height of each page.

```
  webview.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");

            //webview.setWebViewClient(new WebPLZZClient());
            //webview.setWebViewClient(new WebClient());    
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams bq1=webview.getLayoutParams();
            bq1.height=LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            webview.setLayoutParams(bq1);

            webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/KH_Brown_Fixed_Layout/",temp1,  "text/html", "utf-8",null);      
            webview.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.getContentHeight(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].scrollHeight);");
```

But I am not able to get the content height of each page, at least I want to get the height of first two pages.

Comment: Thanks in advance please help me instead of decrementing point,please sorry for any mistake i did

Comment: please tell me the way so solve this problem,please

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and resolved it by clearing the view and re-measuring with a small size prior to loading the view again.

e.g.

```
webView.clearView();
webView.measure(10, 10);
```

Comment: Hey furqi thanks a lot but i want to get the actual content height so after this can i use that.

Comment: follow this tutorial
http://android.pimmos.com/2011/03/24/how-to-retrieve-the-contentwidth-of-a-webview/

Comment: Hey furqi i saw the example but did not get how it 'll be benificial to me ,will you please explain??

Comment: Dear Furqui i am loading 3 html page one by one in for loop so after loading if i am trying to getcontentheight of each page one by one in foor loop so it is showing 0,0,some value of total content